# MongoDB $unwind more than one field and sort by timestamp

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have created one query in that query in that query I am using $unwind more than one field. Query response is fine but my senior suggest me this is wrong query. Because query response is not in proper format and not in ascending order of r_y_b_phasetimestamp timestamp. I given query as follows:

```
 db.energy.aggregate([
    { 
        $project: { EventTS: 1, RPhaseVoltage: 1, YPhaseVoltage:1, BPhaseVoltage:1} 
    },
    {
        $unwind: {
            path: "$RPhaseVoltage",
            includeArrayIndex: "arrayIndex",
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: {
            path: "$YPhaseVoltage",
            includeArrayIndex: "arrayIndex",
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: {
            path: "$BPhaseVoltage",
            includeArrayIndex: "arrayIndex",
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        }
    },
    {
      $match: {
            $and: [ 
                {RPhaseVoltage: {$ne: null}},
                {YPhaseVoltage: {$ne: null}},
                {BPhaseVoltage: {$ne: null}},
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id:0,
            EventTS:1,
            RPhaseVoltage: 1,
            YPhaseVoltage: 1,
            BPhaseVoltage:1,
            r_y_b_phasetimestamp: {
                "$add": [
                    { "$subtract": ["$EventTS", new Date("1970-01-01")]},
                    { "$multiply": [ 60000, "$arrayIndex" ] }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        "rvoltage_data":["$r_y_b_phasetimestamp", "$RPhaseVoltage"],
        "yvoltage_data":["$r_y_b_phasetimestamp", "$YPhaseVoltage"],
        "bvoltage_data":["$r_y_b_phasetimestamp", "$BPhaseVoltage"]
      }
    },
    {
        $sort:{
            r_y_b_phasetimestamp:-1
        }
    }
]);
```

My sample of collection as follows

```
    { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("57742e0f8d8b8fdf278b45d1"), 
    "EventTS" : ISODate("2016-06-24T12:30:00.000+0000"), 
    "RPhaseVoltage" : [ 
        null, 
        231.81, 
        231.81, 
        null, 
        231.42
    ], 
    "YPhaseVoltage" : [ 
        229.95, 
        229.95, 
        null, 
        null, 
        231.32
    ], 
    "BPhaseVoltage" : [
        null, 
        231.44, 
        231.44, 
        null, 
        null
    ]
}
```

My graph output link is [Graph Plotting Link](https://jsfiddle.net/skaka/b7yhzvo6/). This query i am using for graph plotting. Please suggest me my query is wrong and why graph is plotting likw this

Comment: Given the sample document, what do you expect for the result of aggregation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using `$project` 2 times. when you use `$project`, only the projected values are passed to the next part of pipeline. before using sort you are not projecting `r_y_b_phasetimestamp`. so, `r_y_b_phasetimestamp` will be undefined when sorting and will result in unsorted results. try passing `r_y_b_phasetimestamp:"$r_y_b_phasetimestamp"` after `"bvoltage_data":["$r_y_b_phasetimestamp", "$BPhaseVoltage"]` . so the final code is

```
db.energy.aggregate([
{ 
    $project: { EventTS: 1, RPhaseVoltage: 1, YPhaseVoltage:1, BPhaseVoltage:1} 
},
{
    $unwind: {
        path: "$RPhaseVoltage",
        includeArrayIndex: "arrayIndex",
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
},
{
    $unwind: {
        path: "$YPhaseVoltage",
        includeArrayIndex: "arrayIndex",
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
},
{
    $unwind: {
        path: "$BPhaseVoltage",
        includeArrayIndex: "arrayIndex",
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
},
{
  $match: {
        $and: [ 
            {RPhaseVoltage: {$ne: null}},
            {YPhaseVoltage: {$ne: null}},
            {BPhaseVoltage: {$ne: null}},
        ]
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        _id:0,
        EventTS:1,
        RPhaseVoltage: 1,
        YPhaseVoltage: 1,
        BPhaseVoltage:1,
        r_y_b_phasetimestamp: {
            "$add": [
                { "$subtract": ["$EventTS", new Date("1970-01-01")]},
                { "$multiply": [ 60000, "$arrayIndex" ] }
            ]
        }
    }
},
{
  $project: {
    "rvoltage_data":["$r_y_b_phasetimestamp", "$RPhaseVoltage"],
    "yvoltage_data":["$r_y_b_phasetimestamp", "$YPhaseVoltage"],
    "bvoltage_data":["$r_y_b_phasetimestamp", "$BPhaseVoltage"],
    r_y_b_phasetimestamp:"$r_y_b_phasetimestamp"
  }
},
{
    $sort:{
        r_y_b_phasetimestamp:-1
    }
}
]);
```

Comment: showing error "$r_y_b_phasetimestamp is not definded"

Comment: can you try `r_y_b_phasetimestamp:1` instead of  `r_y_b_phasetimestamp:$r_y_b_phasetimestamp`?

Comment: this has nothing to do with using $project more than once - there is no issue having multiple project stages in the same pipeline.

Comment: yes. you can have multiple $project in pipeline but you need to pass all the values needed for next pipeline. i think i may have not explained properly in my answer. edited it to better explain it.